# bug of 'clear text form' script

Tags: javascript, forms

I use little script to clear text form content. It looks neat, but there is one bug.

If I start writing, and just click somewhere within the form all content is deleted.

Any ideas how to fix this??

To see it in action visit:

http://www.sandrophoto.com/2011/11/28/five-photography-tips-from-celebrated-pros/#comment

Start writing something, than just click inside form. see? text gets removed, this is not the behavior I need.

code:

```
<textarea tabindex="4" rows="10" cols="100%" id="comment" name="comment"
    onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()"
    onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Write your comment':this.value;">
    Write your comment</textarea>
```

Is there a way to make this clear text action to happen only once with default text? and than remain static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 things happening within that textarea:

1. onclick: Clear the textarea
2. onfocus: Select this textarea
3. onblur: if its blank, then replace it with `Write your comment`

The one you need to edit is **action 1. (onclick)** because its clearing it everytime the user clicks regardless of what the current value is. You need it to only clear if the contents is the default ie: `Write your comment`.

1. should be: onclick: if value is `Write your Comment` then clear otherwise do nothing.

So your code should look like so:

```
<textarea tabindex="4" rows="10" cols="100%" id="comment" name="comment"
  onclick="if (this.value=='Write your comment'){this.value='';}" 
  onfocus="this.select()"
  onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Write your comment':this.value;">
  Write your comment</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make it conditional to `this.value` containing default text if it is to be cleared.

I am sorry I can't provide a code example. I am not confident enough with html to make sure I am not misleading you.